# Question about Named Views of vue router4

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I use the `defineComponent` function to define the vue component and store it in `Map<String, Component>`,like this:

```
const vueComponent1 = defineComponent({name:'la-dashboard-index',template: 'vueComponent1</div>'})
const vueComponent2 = defineComponent({name:'la-desktop',template: '<div>vueComponent2</div>'})
this.vueComponents.set('la-dashboard-index', vueComponent1);
this.vueComponents.set('la-desktop', vueComponent2);
```

Now,component `la-desktop` redirect to `la-dashboard-index`(eg:`la-desktop` mapping path '/',l`a-dashboard-index` mapping path 'la/dashboard/index')

This `la-desktop` component works fine and the browser displays 'vueComponent2', but redirecting to `la-dashboard-index` component doesn't work

```
Module.register('la-dashboard', {
    type: 'core',
    name: 'dashboard',
    routes: {
        index: {
            components: {
                default: 'la-dashboard-index',
            },
            path: 'index',
        },
    },
});
```

the  type of `routes.index.components` is `Record<string, Component> | {default:string};`

```
//register `la-dashboard-index` component , template: '<div>Hello world</div>'
LaserAdmin.Component.register('la-dashboard-index', () => import('./page/la-dashboard-index'));

Module.register('la-dashboard', {
    type: 'core',
    name: 'dashboard',
    routes: {
        index: {
            components: {
                default: 'la-dashboard-index',
            },
            path: 'index',
        },
    },
});
```

Not display `Hello world` in browser..

[image]